# Initialise a html input text field from a php variable

Tags: php, html

I'm a beginner to web programming and need help with html input field initialisation from a php variable. I have one php file with a table with input fields and buttons etc. javascript and jquery is used to handle the processing. Now I want to get data from a server which will be stored in php variables. This is a code extract:

```
<body>
<php?
$voltage = "012";
// $_POST['voltage']; // tried this

?>

<table>
    <td><input name="GETVOLTS_textfield" type="text" id="GETVOLTS_textfield" value="<?php echo $_POST['voltage'];?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
        %</td>
</table>
</body>
```

I get a message Undefined index : voltage
At this stage I am working with XAMPP localhost and don't have any database, I need to be able to handle the variables locally before worrying about the DB.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**isset()**](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.isset.php&ei=BFbOU_e2JqaZ0QX4uIG4DA&usg=AFQjCNEilnOC2VNydDdQDAXjnJjWAYf6Mg&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGE)

```
<input name="GETVOLTS_textfield" type="text" id="GETVOLTS_textfield" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['voltage'])?$_POST['voltage']:'';?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> I get a message Undefined index : voltage

Was there a `voltage` value posted in the form?  There's an order of events taking place here.  First your server-side code executes, then the page renders, *then* the user posts the form value to server-side code.  So if in the first step you're looking for a form value:

```
$_POST['voltage'];
```

That value isn't going to be there because the user *hasn't posted it yet*.  You can test for the value before trying to use it:

```
if (isset($_POST['voltage'])) {
    // the value exists
}
```

This is commonly used when the same page (and, thus, the same server-side code) is used for both creating the form and handling the posted form.  If that's the case for you then you'll need to include such conditionals because the server-side code can't use form values that aren't posted yet.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the variable $voltage your code should look like this:

```
<input name="GETVOLTS_textfield" type="text" id="GETVOLTS_textfield" value="<?php echo $voltage; ?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
```

you can set $voltage with a specific posted var

```
$voltage = $_POST['voltage'];
```

but you should test if your variable $_POST['voltage'] is set, because you will get your mentioned error if nothing or just this variable is not posted

you can do this with [isset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['voltage'])
{
   $voltage = $_POST['voltage'];
}
else
{
   $voltage = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$voltage`. The `$_POST` array will only have values in it if a form submitted values to your script.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for so many replies. It's working now I will add the isset function for checking. The problem was solved by changing to
 
    <td><input name="GETVOLTS_textfield" type="text" id="GETVOLTS_textfield"      value="<?php echo $voltage;?>" size="3" maxlength="3" /> %</td>

I can now pass these on to the DB handling file using jquery $.post()
Thanks so much.

Comment: BTW @Think Different the isset needed to be in () like value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['voltage'])?$_POST['voltage']:$voltage);?>"

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input name="GETVOLTS_textfield" type="text" id="GETVOLTS_textfield" value="<?php echo $voltage;?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
```

Comment: change <php? to <?php

Answer (score 0):

1) May-be you should consider doing : (despite it's not recommanded, that's what you're trying to do)

```
$voltage = "012";
$_POST['voltage'] = $voltage;
```

2) You don't need $_POST variables. Just echo $voltage !

Comment: Yeah, totally, but I wanted to show him there was also an error at the beggining of the code (or that's what I think he is trying to do).

In this case, assigning $_POST value is useless, yes.